# Foreign keys to non-domain model in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to map a poperty as foreign key to a table which exists in the database but not in the current POCO model.

For example in my Authentication model I have a AspNetUsers table with an ID. This lives in a separate project.

In my domain model, I do not directly reference the models in the authentication project, but certain tables (objects) need the UserId. Now even though I can just define the user ID as properties, but then I lose the referential integrity etc that comes with having a foreign key.

Otherwise I have to run a special script on the database to set up the relationships. Is there no way for EF to model such a constraint?

Comment: I don't understand.  The database enforces the Foreign Key, not EF.

Comment: Yes but you can model foreign key constraints declaratively or fluently in your EF model when both models are in the EF poco model which are then applied to the database during migration. Question is "is it possible to when one of the tables is not in the EF POCO model but in the database?"

Comment: If you are using Code First and want to create a FK between one table in your model and some other table you have to use a custom SQL Command in the migration.

Comment: OK, thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft